# Is sending a file with multiple TCP streams a good idea?

Tags: streaming, tcp

Imagine I got a large file and I want to send it through a TCP connection. The typical way is to use a stream and send continues bytes through it. But the question is, is it possible to send this file using multiple parallel streams? And if the answer is yes, does it decrease the transfer time? And how can I manage multiple chunks of data coming from different streams ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon to do this and it can speed things up, although its more complex to code, and the performs CE increase (if any) will depend on the connectivity to the remote. Its less then ideal from an Internet health POV because it trys to defeat congestion control.

How this is implemented is outside of scope for Superuser, but common implementations (which are done client side) is to put the content on a web server which allows chunking and then have the client request multiple chunks simultaneously and merge them together.  This is a solved problem.